# Clean react useState in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

im trying to clean the state every time the effect is called, here is my code

```
const [id,setNodos] = useState([]);

useEffect(() =>{
    {props.data.channel.map((canales,i) => (
        setNodos(prevState => [...prevState, {channelId: canales.channelId, x:(dimensions.width/4)*Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * ((i/ props.data.channel.length)+ 0.75))}])
))}
},[props.data])
```

I want to clean id every time useEffect is triggered.

Comment: What does the code you posted do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since the state is stored in `id` and you have its setter `setNodos`, you can simply set its state back to the original state `[]` like this: `setNodos([]);`. Or if that's not what you mean with "clean", then you simply have to write the logic yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't update state on for each node. This is not optimized. Theoretical each setState runs component rerender. But react probably will optimize this operation and don''t rerender compoent unitl useEffect will end.

You should map your data to 'nodos' array and the set it.

And there is convenion. if you have setNodos the 'id' should be named 'nodos'.

```
    const [id,setNodos] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() =>{
        const nodes = props.data.channel.map((channel,i) => ({
            channelId: channel.channelId, 
            x:(dimensions.width/4)*Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * ((i/ props.data.channel.length)+ 0.75))
        }))
        setNodos(prevNodes => ({
            ...prevNodes,
            ...nodes
        }))
    },[props.data, dimensions, setNodos])
```

ps. you can install some spell checker in IDE.